# Discord.py: client not working inside tasks?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to loop a task that would check a member's activity from a certain server every hour, and sending a message on a specific channel if they are still on the same activity. Here is the part of code I need help with:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from keep_alive import keep_alive

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)

@tasks.loop(seconds = 10, count = 1)
async def checkactiv():
  guild = client.get_guild(int(####))
  member = guild.get_member(int(####))
  channel = client.get_channel(int(####))

  if member.activity.name.lower() == "a certain game":
    await channel.send("ignore this test message")
  
checkactiv.start()
```

I have tried this as a command and it works, but I want it to loop automatically every hour or so (I made it 10 seconds as a test). The error I get is saying that **guild** and **channel** are a NoneType, this wasn't the case when I was using as a command like this:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  guild = client.get_guild(int(####))
  member = guild.get_member(int(####))

  await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
  if member.activity.name.lower() == "a certain game":
    await ctx.send("still playing")
```

I am not entirely sure what the problem is, but I am assuming that client cannot be called under a task? It obviously works just fine under @client.command, but not within a task loop. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Does it have something to do with my client being **commands.Bot** rather than **discord.Client**? I have commands on the Discord bot that is not displayed here so I can't try changing my client.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try using `client.fetch_guild` instead of `client.get_guild`

Comment: I tried using it but I am getting this error: "TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine".

Not sure why, haven't fully grasped the concept of coroutines yet.

Comment: Have you awaited the `fetch_guild` method?

Answer (score 0):

`client.get_x` gets the object from the internal cache, when you start the task the cache is not fully loaded yet, you can use the `client.wait_until_ready` method to wait till the cache is ready:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds = 10, count = 1)
async def checkactiv():
    guild = client.get_guild(int(####))
    member = guild.get_member(int(####))
    channel = client.get_channel(int(####))


@checkactiv.before_loop  # it's called before the actual task runs
async def before_checkactiv():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
```